Place every item from a text file into an array but detect headers/titles
I have text files that contain
Firstname: xxx
Lastname: yyy
Login: abcd

It has many others entries for other definitions but all in the same format header: data
I would like to use an array in PowerShell to read these and would like to do
$array.firstname
$array.Login 

to get me the the data.
Can this be done ?
We currently use a long regex to spit out the data but this is becoming unwieldy and would like to simplify this.

Does each file contain only unique header values (so only 1 Login line per file for example)?

Please add a [mcve] to your question. As a general (non-regex) solution you might use ConvertFrom-String with a custom template.


I would like to use an array in PowerShell to read these and would like to do

Arrays are just fixed-sized containers of multiples of something, they don't really do anything in and of themselves.
If you want a thing that has arbitrary named properties like firstname or login then you want a custom object.
You can use the -match regex operator to identify and extract the label and value in each line, like this:
$filePath = 'C:\path\to\file.txt'

# create an ordered dictionary to temporarily hold the label-value pairs
$properties = [ordered]@{}

# read the file into memory line-by-line
Get-Content $filePath |ForEach-Object {
  # test whether the line matches the `label: value` format
  if ($_ -match '^([^:]+):\s*(.*)$') {
    # ... and if so, extract the values matched by the capture groups
    $properties[$Matches[1]] = $Matches[2]
  }
}

# finally convert the ordered dictionary to an object
$myObject = [pscustomobject]$properties

$myObject now contains an object with properties named for the header labels found in the file, so you can now reference $myObject.Login etc.

If you want to avoid regex altogether, use String.Split() instead of -match+$Matches:
# read the file into memory line-by-line
Get-Content $filePath |ForEach-Object {
  # test whether the line has a `:`
  if ($_ -like '*:*') {
    $label,$value = $_.Split(':', 2) |ForEach-Object Trim
    $properties[$label] = $value
  }
}


This is exactly what we use and I would like to move away from regex

@BillySmith I thought you wanted to move away from an unwieldy regex pattern - is ^([^:]+):\s*(.*)$ too much?

Indeed we do, that string.Split() Code gets a Cannot index into a null array

@BillySmith the second example is a partial snippet, you still need to define $properties = [ordered]@{} ahead of time

Hi Mathias,
I appreciate your help, now I get all entities  in $properties.Firstname

Did you perhaps accidentally add the -Raw parameter when calling Get-Content?

Yes -raw is used by get-content and if I load the file in Notepad++ I see CRLF at the end of each line.
Removed -raw and got it working

ConvertFrom-StringData
In Powershell 5.1 you cannot specify delimiter. It expects = as delimiter so first replace : with =. In case there are multiple : in a line we will replace only the first occurrence by using regex and capture groups.
$hashtable = (Get-Content .\data.txt -Raw) -replace '(?m)^(.*?):(.*$)', '$1=$2' | ConvertFrom-StringData
$hashtable.Login
$hashtable.Firstname
$hashtable.Lastname

In PowerShell 7+ -Delimiter parameter was introduced
$hashtable = Get-Content .\data.txt -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':' 
$hashtable.Login
$hashtable.Firstname
$hashtable.Lastname

